# How are Windows Environment variables evaluated?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

If I have a `System` and `User` environment variable with the same name, how are they processed? Are they concatenated? Does the `user` variable override the `system` variable? Taking that into account, if I need to add something to the `Path` variable, where is it more convenient to add it?

Answer (score 23):

Everything [splash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256544/splash) says in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5127106/2657515) is correct. To be absolutely clear, there is a difference between how the user path environment variable is evaluated, and the other user environment variables are evaluated. A regular user environment variable overrides completely a system one with the same name if both exist, but only for the specific user it is specified for. **However, the user path  variables is treated differently**. It is **appended** to the system path variable when evaluating, rather than completely replacing it. I believe splash states that, but they do it so concisely I think it needs spelling out.

Answer (score 22):

I think this article should answer you question: [Environment variables in Windows NT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100843/en-us)

> **User environment variables**
>
> User environment variables can be
>   viewed from Control Panel as well. The
>   user may add, delete or modify the
>   environment variables in the User
>   Environment Variables for User field.
>   These variables take precedence over
>   system environment variables. The user
>   path is appended to the system path.

Comment: that article is erroneus. Try delete the %PATH% of the user path. Then everything that need the path don't going to work properly. I'm thinking that the user variables override the system variables. So if i have an empty user Path variable i'm going to have alot of problems to execute almost everything. To reestablish the value you could delete that variable or set it again with the %PATH%; prefix. You could use powershell: set-itemproperty hkcu:\Environment -name Path -value "%PATH%"

Comment: @Ps1CsCpp, I don't think what you're saying is correct. The article states that user PATH entries are appended to system-wide PATH. For your scenario, an empty user PATH would have no effect on the PATH provided to a process. Said another way, adding an empty string to the end of the system PATH will have no effect. I have tested this on Windows 8.

Answer (score 19):

Everything that [splash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256544/splash) and [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2316724/simon) say in their answers are correct. The idea that the user path variable is appended has been highlighted, and I believe the consequences of that difference require some additional treatment.

> Path = %Path% (System) ; %Path% (User)

When you execute an executable program (or any executable script, such as `.bat`, `.vbs`, etc.) you do not need to provide the fully qualified path.

For instance, to run `java`, you can type in any of these:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin/java -version

java.exe -version

java -version
```

The first example uses a fully qualified path. This will always use the version of the Java at that exact path.

The second example will go through each of the directories in the `%Path%` environment variable, looking for an executable file named `java.exe`. It will run the very first one that is found, and stop searching. **If there are two files named `java.exe` somewhere on the `%Path%`, only the first one found is used.**

The third example, like the second, will iterate over the directories listed in the `%Path%`. In addition, because a file extension was not provided, a list of executable file extensions are appended to the name of the file, in the order specified in the `%PATHEXT%` environment variable. **If there are several files named `java.com`, `java.exe`, `java.bat`, etc. somewhere on the `%Path%`, only the first one found is used.**

You can see the list of executable path extensions on your system by creating the following batch file:

```
@echo off
echo %PATHEXT%
pause
```

On my machine, these are:

> .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY

## What does all this mean?

In ***stark contrast*** to other environment variable, the user path does not allow you to override the system path. The exact opposite is the case. From the examples above, there are many cases where you may wish to change the default version of Java. However, if there is already a Java version listed in the system path, that is the version that will ALWAYS be found first, because the path is searched in order, left-to-right, with the user path appended on the right-hand side, with the system path on the left.

## What can I do about it?

If you do not have access to system environment variables, you cannot override default programs on the system path by using the user path. (In fact, it **must** be this way, or certain programs would stop working correctly, and would open your system to tampering by malicious software. Nobody wants that.)

Instead, you must use a fully qualified path if you must use a specific version.

Comment: Great answer. However, why then does the context in which a program is started matter?In my case, to have Qt enabled in TexStudio when using PythonTex, I must start TexStudio from the Anaconda prompt and not the Cmd prompt. In both cases the environment variables and paths are the same!

Comment: That would be a good topic for a new question. (I've started using Anaconda myself within the past year, but am not sure of details on how environment variables are made available in that shell.)