# windows 10 mvn -version The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly, this environment variable is needed to run this program

Tags: java, windows, maven, environment-variables

There are a lot of similar posts on here, such as
[Showing JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly when I check Maven version in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68503422/showing-java-home-is-not-defined-correctly-when-i-check-maven-version-in-windows) and
[How do I fix maven error The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680125/how-do-i-fix-maven-error-the-java-home-environment-variable-is-not-defined-corre)

But none of them have helped me.  I do not have \bin on the end of my JAVA_HOME variable.

```
C:\Users\user1>mvn -version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.

C:\Users\user1>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_351

C:\Users\user1>java -version
java version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.19+9-LTS-224)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.19+9-LTS-224, mixed mode)
```

How are the system environment variables evaluated?  Do system environment variables take precedence over user environment variables?  And do path variables at top take precedence over those beneath them?  How do I work with multiple JDK versions?

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions in one. You didn't explain your actual issue. What is really the problem you are having?

Comment: [How are Windows Environment variables evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126512)